# iis host markdown files

Tags: iis, markdown

I've gone the route of adding the MIME type to IIS so that the files can be displayed by the browser and used a browser plugin to render the content, but this isn't really what we want.

Is there a way to serve markdown files as HTML from just an IIS site?

Is there  an IIS handler that could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS 7 or above, you could use a custom handler.

[MSDN Blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saveenr/2008/12/23/up-with-markdown-as-an-authoring-format-or-sample-code-for-an-iis7-markdown-handler/)

You would just need to rename the extension to .markdown and it takes care of the rest.

Comment: I read that article before posting my question. None of the source links in the article work.